# Pandas applying slice_replace with for loop and conditional statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to loop through a column in a dataframe, and if the value(s) in the column meet a certain criteria, utilize the slice_replace function to update only part of the string

For example, if I had the below:

```
data = {'INPUT':['AB-TEF', 'AB0HFD', 'AB0GRD','AB0JEC','AB-JOD']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    INPUT
0  AB-TEF
1  AB0HFD
2  AB0GRD
3  AB0JEC
4  AB-JOD
```

I want to change all the zeros to dashes, where I'd end up with:

```
    INPUT
0  AB-TEF
1  AB-HFD
2  AB-GRD
3  AB-JEC
4  AB-JOD
```

I've tried doing:

```
for i in df['INPUT']:
    if i.startswith('AB0'):
        i = i.str.slice_replace(start=2,stop=3,repl='-')
```

But I get:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Comment: Try: ``df.INPUT.str.replace("AB0", "AB-")``

Comment: `df["INPUT"] = df["INPUT"].str.replace("0", "-")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df["INPUT"] = df["INPUT"].str.replace('^AB0', 'AB-', regex=True)
```

The `^` before `AB0` is a regular expression symbol to indicate matching from the start of text. This is the same as your test of  `startswith('AB0')`. Without it, you will mistakenly also replace `AB-AB0` with `AB-AB-`.

`regex=True` is to tell pandas that the first parameter consist of regular expression so that the `^` can get its special meaning.